# Export GridView to Excel not working when AllowSorting set to true

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm displaying some Data from a Sql Database through `ObjectDataSource` in a `GridView`. I've also enabled the user to export the data to excel with this code :

```
  public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
{

}



private void ExportGridToExcel()
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.ClearHeaders();
    Response.Charset = "";
    string FileName = "Results" + DateTime.Now + ".xls";
    StringWriter strwritter = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter htmltextwrtter = new HtmlTextWriter(strwritter);
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + FileName);
    GridView1.GridLines = GridLines.Both;
    GridView1.HeaderStyle.Font.Bold = true;
    GridView1.RenderControl(htmltextwrtter);
    Response.Write(strwritter.ToString());
    Response.End();

}


protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ExportGridToExcel();
}
```

All working fine. However, when I set `AllowSorting=true` in my `GridView`  and click the export button I get following error: ystem.InvalidOperationException:

> RegisterForEventValidation can only be called during Render();

It's not a massive issue as I don't necessarily need to allow sorting in the `GridView` but I'm curious what the issue is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this attribute to the @ Page declaration:

```
EnableEventValidation="false"
```